# Por que o Node.js não executa o sucrase – um pacote instalado localmente?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarn

No Node.js, instalei no `cmd` o `yarn` (não consigo usar o `yarn` e estou usando o `npm`), mas o mesmo não funciona. Optei por usar o `npm` e agora ao tentar usar a biblioteca sucrase (install: `npm install --save-dev sucrase`) e o `nodemon`, não roda.

Aparece isso:

```
...
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Abaixo o Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "teste",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "cursonode",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \\\"Error> no test specified\\\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Cesar Vitor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Coloque aqui o conteúdo do seu arquivo `package.json`

Comment: Olá Lucas, adicionei acima o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os comandos [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) ou [`yarn run`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/) para executar qualquer binário que tenha sido instalado localmente. Isso significa que você pode executar "CLIs" fornecidas por pacotes sem o prefixo `./node_modules/.bin`.

Por exemplo, se você tiver **instalado localmente** o pacote [`sucrase`](https://sucrase.io/), e executá-lo usando um dos dois comandos acima, o Yarn ou NPM gerenciarão o comando para você.

Então, uma vez que você tiver instalado o seu pacote:

```
yarn add sucrase --dev # Para Yarn
npm install sucrase --save-dev # Para NPM
```

Você pode configurar o seguinte no campo [`scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) do seu `package.json`:

```js
// [...]
"scripts": {
  "build": "yarn run sucrase ./your-file.tsx" // Ou `npm run sucrase ./your-file.tsx`
}
// [...]
```

Lembre-se que o Yarn e NPM interpretam o que você coloca após o `yarn run` (ou `npm run`) como um comando normal. Você só poderá usar, no entanto, os comandos instalados localmente no seu pacote. Para ver todos os binários disponíveis, basta olhar os arquivos dentro da pasta `node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: Agradeço, após fazer o recomendado, apareceu um novo erro. Alguém conhece como resolver?

Comment: Remova a resposta que você criou e edite a pergunta adicionando os detalhes do erro...

Answer (score 0):

após fazer o que recomendou apareceu um novo erro:

> npm run sucrase ./src/app.js

npm ERR! missing script: sucrase

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edilson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-14T16_43_03_487Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! celke@1.0.0 build: `npm run sucrase ./src/app.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the celke@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edilson\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-14T16_43_03_527Z-debug.log

Answer (score -1):

A solução pode configurar o campo `scripts`.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "suncrase": "suncrase-node src/server.js"
},
...
```

Depois você executa o comando `npm run sucrase`;

Comment: se voce rodar sucrase-node src/server.js diretamente deveria funcionar.

Comment: mas fazer um script próprio pra isso é melhor. Então depois de fazer isso vc pode rodar esse script, usando yarn: yarn sucrase, ou npm: npm run sucrase